# How to prevent hiding the keyboard of the activity when DialogFragment open

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

I have an edit text in the activity and a view which open the DialogFragment.

if i click on the edittext keypad opens and then if i click on the view which open the dialog Fragment the keyboard hides. i still want to show the keypad of the activity.

i have set windowsoftinputmode of the activity in the manifest

> adjustNothing

also tried with

> statealwaysvisible

but not able to keep the keyboard up what could be the solution